How to have a single anchor link scroll to two different sections in a single page in react
I have a sidebar section and a content section. Sidebar section basically has anchor links that basically makes the respective Content scroll to top on Right hand side.
But I also want the sidebar link that i clicked scroll to top as well.
Summary: By click of single anchor link i want the anchor tag and the content both to scroll to top. Is it possible?


 const items = Array.from({ length: 15 }, (_, index) => `items from strapi ${index}`);
...
...


<div className="flex gap-4 items-start mt-16 mx-16">
                <div className="aside">
                    <ul>
                        {items.map((item, index) => (
                        <li className="h-16" key={index}>
                            <a
                                onClick={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                const targetElement = document.getElementById(`${index}`);
                                if (targetElement) {
                                    targetElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
                                }
                                }} 
                                href={`#${index}`}>{item}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className='flex flex-col'>
                    {items.map((item, index) => (
                        <div id={`${index}`} className='flex pt-16'>
                          {`${index}`} {loaderData?.overview}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>



How to achieve this? In my given snippet only the content in RHS scrolls to top

Yes, it's possible. You can achieve this by using the scrollIntoView method on both the target content and the clicked anchor link. Here's how you can modify your code, by using clickedElement.scrollIntoView
In this code, I've added unique IDs to both the anchor links and the content divs. When an anchor link is clicked, the onClick handler gets the target content and the clicked anchor link using their IDs, and then scrolls both of them into view.
<div className="flex gap-4 items-start mt-16 mx-16">
    <div className="aside">
        <ul>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
            <li className="h-16" key={index}>
                <a
                    onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    const targetElement = document.getElementById(`content-${index}`);
                    const clickedElement = document.getElementById(`link-${index}`);
                    if (targetElement && clickedElement) {
                        targetElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
                        clickedElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
                    }
                    }} 
                    id={`link-${index}`}
                    href={`#content-${index}`}>{item}
                </a>
            </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div className='flex flex-col'>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
            <div id={`content-${index}`} className='flex pt-16'>
              {`${index}`} {loaderData?.overview}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
</div>


Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

No, this is an implemented approach

Then please explain the solution. What did you actually change in order to solve the solution - FYI

Sure, I'll elaborate on this.

Yes, for sure. I have added an explanation for my approach

Please (re)read the linked article

This solution does not work as expected. Now only sidebar Link scrolls to top/view but the respective content does not scroll to top

Okay, I'll look into this and find a better approach accordingly based on the produced issue .
Thankyou
